# Como ver quais tabelas acessadas no postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Como visualizar as tabelas que estão sendo  acessadas pelo comando select ?

EX: `select *from pg_stats`

Gostaria de obter as tabelas que estão tendo mais acesso em um determinado dia no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Internamente, o `PostgreSQL` possui um subsistema (Conhecido como [*Statistics Collector*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html)) responsável pelo monitoramento de todas as atividades que são executadas pelo servidor.

Essas informações de monitoramento são disponibilizadas por meio de [algumas dezenas de `VIEWS` de sistema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE).

A `VIEW` chamada [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) contém informações em tempo real sobre sobre todas os processos em execução, inclusive as consultas que estão sendo executadas naquele momento.

Por exemplo, para se consultar a atividade na database de nome `foobar`:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'foobar';
```

Outra alternativa, é utilizar um analizador de log para colher as estatísticas a partir dos arquivos de log gerados pelo Postgres.

O [`PgBadger`](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger) faz esse tabalho muito bem, gerando relatórios em formato `HTML`.